# Android как связать два телефона

Tags: android

Есть задача: связать два телефона по интернету. Телефоны могут быть подключены как по Wi-Fi, так и по мобильному интернету (даже между разными странами). Конструкция, по возможности должны быть автономна.

Один телефон должен выступать в роли сервера, а второй — в роли клиента. Клиент должен запрашивать информацию (можно сказать, поток байтов) и отправлять.

---

При помощи чего это можно реализовать?

Comment: Может с помощью Telegram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Связать по интернету" плохо описывает условия. Можем ли мы быть уверены, что они оба подключены к WiFi? Будет ли это один и тот же WiFi, или нет? Можем ли мы задействовать для этого сервер, или конструкция должна быть полностью автономной? Это сильно влияет на выбор решения.

Проблем, которые требуется решить, несколько:

1. Обеспечить связность. Далеко не всегда два устройства, подключенные к интернету, могут взаимодействовать напрямую. Решением является или ограничение условий (подключение к одному WiFi), либо использование посредника в облаке (например GCM, Firebase Storage, Firebase RealtimeDatabase, Google Play сервисы, собственный сервер, и куча других вариантов).
2. Обнаружение. Нужно, чтобы устройство-клиент нашло устройство-сервер. В случае общего WiFi можно использовать Dynamic DNS или рассылку IP-бродкастов. В более общем случае - использование посредника в облаке.
3. Собственно, передача информации. Самый простой этап. Возможностей куча: от прямого использования сокетов до HTTP.

По сообщению разбросаны ключевые слова. Гуглите и выбирайте.

Если у вас задача связана с играми, то посмотрите на сервисы, которые предоставляет Google, например, [Real-time Multiplayer](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer)

Comment: Мдя... Согласен, как-то я совсем без деталей написал. Вообще задача такова: два пользователя заходят в приложения, подключаются к одной комнате и нажимают кнопку "готов". Приложение получает их имена в онлайн игре (PC игра), убеждается в создании общей комнаты в игре и начинает мониторить статус игры. После завершения игры, победившему пользователю показывается сообщение.

Comment: С Google Play Services я никогда не сталкивался, они же смогут выполнить роль сервера? Или тут практически никак не обойтись без своего сервера?

Comment: Судя по описанию, из имеющихся сервисов что-то можно подобрать. Попробуйте Paly Services и Realtime Database.